# Connecting CCTV coax-based video surveillance cameras to a Synology IP solution

Tags: video-recording, conversion, hardware, recommendation, digital-recording

[I hope this is on-topic here as it appears somewhat related questions have been asked before]

I have a 4-camera analog CCTV system using coax cable. I'd like to replace my analog DVR (digital video recorder) with a digital solution leveraging my Synology NAS.

From my research, I believe I need a video encoder that converts BNC coax cable signals into an IP stream.

- Is this correct?
- Any recommendations for products that would do the job? Bonus for solutions that plug into Synology's Surveillance Station solution.

Comment: Welcome! BNC is a connector and coax is a (very broad) description of cable. You need to find out what signal the cameras output. There are some unusual ones that security systems have used over the years. Then, if it is an analog signal, you'll need something that can convert analog to digital and then encode RTP or SRTP. I haven't done the math, but my gut says it would be less expensive to just replace the cameras.

Comment: Thanks. There are some products (e.g., https://www.axis.com/products/axis-m71-series) that appear to do this - I will attempt to check with them if they solve my use case